# Meteor scope variable to request

Tags: meteor

I currently intercept requests to my app by adding a connectionHandler and running a Fiber for the request:

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function (req, res, next) {
    Fiber(function() {
        // Custom request handling

        next();
    }).run();
});
```

As part of my custom request handling I may call a function defined outside of the Fiber itself. Is there any way (without directly passing a variable defined in the connection handler), that I can get and set variables scoped only to my current request/Fiber? This is as against every request having access to the same variable as would occur in the case of simply setting `variable = 'test';` in the Fiber function.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal here is. When you declare your variable inside a function with the `var` keyword, it will be local to that function.

Comment: Without passing the variable directly to the function I want to call, declaring `var foo` will only be accessible to functions also defined in the same scope ie `function () { var foo = 'bar'; function () { // foo can be accessed in here } }` but `function () {var foo = 'bar';} function () { // foo cannot be accessed directly in here without passing it }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not documented, but [`Meteor.EnvironmentVariable`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js) seems to be what you want. This gives you dynamically-scoped variables which are local to a single fiber. I haven't ever used it myself, but from looking at the source, it seems you'd use it like this:

```js
var envVar = new Meteor.EnvironmentVariable();

Fiber(function() {
    envVar.withValue(5, function() {
      subroutine();
    });
}).run();

function subroutine() {
  console.log(envVar.get()); // 5
}
```

You could also look at [this test](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/d477c8d03bb078f7e8e85dbe4b51db7ae5689573/packages/meteor/dynamics_test.js) in the Meteor source for more examples.

I also found [this EventedMind screencast](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/rlzE5yb_rF0), but I don't have access to them.